# unable to use query in angularFire application

Tags: angular, angularfire2

I am creating an AngularFire app, and this is the code in my app.component.ts:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFireDatabase, FirebaseListObservable } from 
'angularfire2/database';
import { AngularFireAuth } from 'angularfire2/auth';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import * as firebase from 'firebase/app';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  user: Observable<firebase.User>;
  items: FirebaseListObservable<any[]>;
  msgVal: string = '';

  constructor(public afAuth: AngularFireAuth, public af: AngularFireDatabase) {
    this.items = af.list('/messages', {
      query: {
        //I am using a limitToLast: 50 here, but isn't working.
      }
    });

    this.user = this.afAuth.authState;

  }
}
```

The problem is that it isn't compiling, and my text editor (vs code) is returning the following errors:
when I hover over `query: {` : `[ts]
Argument of type '{ query: { limitToLast: number; }; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'QueryFn'. Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'query' does not exist in type 'QueryFn'.`

I can't seem to be able to find the problem, why is this happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you are using the last angularfire2 and firebase version, as I had the same exception. They changed several things with the latest update. Here a link to [angularfire2 latest docs](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/tree/master/docs).

In your case you can fix it like this:

```
constructor(public afAuth: AngularFireAuth, public af: AngularFireDatabase) {
   this.items = af.list('/messages', ref => ref.orderByKey(true).limitToLast(50));
});

   this.user = this.afAuth.authState;
```

}

Comment: I tried it, but here is what I get: `[ts]
Argument of type '{ query: (ref: any) => any; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'QueryFn'.
  Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'query' does not exist in type 'QueryFn'.`

Comment: Thank you, it worked after I changed FirebaseListObservable to AngularFireList.

Comment: Do you know how I can set Order by key to true in the same way?

Comment: You can append the orderByKey method. However keep in mind that you can use only one sorting method per query, as example the following would not work: ref.orderByChild('createdOn').orderByKey(true). I modified my answer adding this part too. Was this what you meant?

Comment: Yes, that was exactly what I meant! Thank you so much!